# C++/ENUM/Type Name/Specifier

Tags: c++, enums

I've searching for hours for that problem and still cant fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum color { brown, green, orange, red, yellow };
enum yn { yes, no };

struct Fruit {
  private:
    char name[32];
    color cl;
    yn annual;
    yn perennial;
    yn tropical;
  public:

};

int main()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`function yn is not a type name`. 
`'annual, perennal, tropical' unknown override specifier`.

Comment: there is no problem with the color but with yn.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: I am only getting warnings about unused private members.

Comment: I am using VS2015 if that matters. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  function "yn" is not a type name Fruit c:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Fruit\Fruit\Source.cpp 12

Comment: Did you post the full source file?

Comment: thats what i need .Yes

Comment: Do you mean *That's what I **did**?*

Comment: Its a part of a program, but i dont think it matters. If i change the name to enum yna the program is working perfectly..

Comment: https://goo.gl/gYGU2U  works for me

Comment: It does matter, and you were right to try a find a minimum compilable program to illustrate your problem, but should have tried to compile it `;-)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yn` is the name of the Bessel function of the second kind for order n.  It may be defined as `double yn(int n, double x);` in `<math.h>`.

You do not include `<math.h>` in the example, but probably do in your code. It is possible that your compiler gets confused about this.  Try renaming the enum to `enum yesno { yes, no };`

Comment: Oh i got it.Thanks :)